# Postfix rewrite sender: why doesn't this work

Tags: postfix, email

I have server A with an IP address only and a dummy FQDN (on the basis all machines should have a FQDN): pants.net.invalid.  All mail is relayed through another server elsewhere, which works fine.

On server A, Postfix rewrites the sender address with `smtp_generic_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/generic`.  According to the Rewrite manual at http://www.postfix.org/ADDRESS_REWRITING_README.html#remote, this should rewrite all outgoing external mail's Sender address:

```
$ cat /etc/postfix/generic
@pants.net.invalid     nick+pants@my.other.server.net
```

but it does not.  `postmap -q nick@pants.net.invalid` returns nothing.

This works:

```
nick@pants.net.invalid     nick+pants@my.other.server.net
```

It seems as though it is doing regex matching even though I specify type `hash:`. Clearly I am misunderstanding the manual.

I don't want to use regex or pcre expressions because there are only a couple of users (root and two others) and I don't want the overhead.

I can specify the users exactly and it works.  But, I would like to know what I am misunderstanding for future reference.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It works. According to the manual http://www.postfix.org/generic.5.html

But your postmap command is faulty. It should read:

```
postmap -q nick@pants.net.invalid hash:/etc/postfix/generic
```